# Device in fstab not mounting at boot

Tags: mount, usb, fstab

The following is in my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
UUID=596ac80a-5571-41dc-a00e-b3270ecfe7c4 / ext3 errors=remount-ro 0 1 

/dev/sdb1 /home/teamspeak/ts3/files/virtualserver_1/channel_527 ext3  nofail,auto,noatime,rw,user 0 0

tmpfs   /var/log   tmpfs   nofail,defaults,noatime,mode=0755,size=5M   0  0
```

but `/dev/sdb1` doesn't mount at boot time (if I write `mount` it doesn't show up in the list) , but it does if I then write `mount -a`

EDIT
It is an usb device, and option nofail needs to be present cause it prevents the machine to halt if plugged out and reboot. Tried _netdev option with no luck.

right after boot  `dmesg | tail`   outputs

```
[    8.774931] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    8.775036]  sdb: sdb1
[    9.115231] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    9.115336] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

then, after `mount -a` it adds:

```
[ 2037.473279] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[ 2037.475895] EXT3 FS on sdb1, internal journal
[ 2037.475916] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
```

Comment: Try removing the nofail so that when it is unable to mount the device, it shows what error its facing in the logs.

Comment: could this be an iscsi device or fc over ethernet? In this case it will not come up because /etc/fstab is mounted before the network service is started. To circumvent this, use the option _netdev.

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk This is plausible enough that you should post it as an answer.

Comment: unluckily nothing suggested here helped